# Why does my method return 66

Tags: java, csv

So I have this method here that should return the amount of lines in a csv file. Pretty simple right? Thing is instead of returning the amount of lines in the csv file(in this case 15) it returns 66. I honestly have know Idea why this would happen. I checked the csv file and verified that it is indeed 15 lines long with no empty lines. Also does anyone know why my Jpanes wont display without those three lines commented lines, my ide says the variables aren't in use anywhere.

```
public static int getLineCount(){
    int line=0;
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data =inputStream.next();//this line is useless but the program doesn't display with out it
            String[] values = data.split(",");//this line is useless but the program doesn't display with out it
            i++;//this line is useless but the program doesn't display with out it
            line++;
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return line;
}
```

Comment: If you want a line count, use `inputStream.nextLine()` not `next()`.

Comment: how about hasNextLine()?

Comment: Yes, you'll need that too.

Comment: I just realized that you meant for 'inputStream.nextLine()' to apply to String data not the while loop. This fixed the issue thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use BufferedReader instead of Scanner:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
while(reader.readLine() != null){
      line++;
}
```

Comment: It says that InputStreamReader() can not accept file because it is a string.

Comment: Look at Uzochis answer. You need to use FileReader(file).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int getLineCount(){
    String csvFilePath = "C:\\Users\\uzochi\\desktop\\txt.csv";
    String line = "";   
    int numberOfLines=0;
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFilePath));
        while (( line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        numberOfLines++;
        }
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    //
    }catch (IOException ex) {
        //
    }
    return numberOfLines;
}
```